# How to use the same definition for an ID parameter and an ID schema property?

Tags: openapi

I am wondering if there is a way in OpenAPI to describe that the `user_id` used as a path parameter is the same type of value as the `id` field of a `User` object. A benefit of this is reusing the description and example.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Test API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /foo/{user_id}:
    get:
      parameters: 
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/user_id'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A user
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
components:
  parameters:
    user_id:
      name: user_id
      in: path
      required: true
      description: the id of a User, from parameters
      example: ghijkl
      schema:
        type: string
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id: 
          type: string
          description: the id of a User, from schemas
          example: abcdef
```

I don't like having to re-define the example and description of the user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a separate schema for the user ID and have the parameter/property `schema` reference the user ID schema:

```yaml
components:
  parameters:
    user_id:
      name: user_id
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserId'   # <-------
  schemas:
    UserId:
      type: string
      description: The ID of a User
      example: abcdef
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id: 
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserId' # <-------
```

Swagger Editor and Swagger UI will fetch the parameter example from the schema example, but the parameter description is currently not fetched from the schema description. Feel free to submit an [enhancement request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues).